# True definition of a function $f$

Tags: calculus, functions, definition, relations

Thomas *Calculus* gives the following definition for a function:

> A function $f$ from a set $D$ to a set $Y$ is a rule that assigns a unique
> value $f(x)$ in $Y$ to each $x$ in $D$.

I have my misgivings as far as this definition for a mathematical function is concerned.

Every $x$ needn't be assigned a unique $f(x)$ from $Y$.

If $x_1, x_2 \in D$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y \in Y$ which is perfectly valid and $y$ is not unique since the same $y$ gets assigned to both $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Am I wrong in my interpretation?

Comment: You have the uniqueness quantifier mixed up and it's not your fault, that is a slightly confusing definition. It's not saying that the $y$ values are all unique, but rather that each $x$ is paired with one and only one $y$. For example, $x=1$ cannot be paired to both $y=2$ and $y=3$.

Comment: Two elements of the domain can be assigned the same value. Unique means that $f(x)$ only takes on one value.

Comment: How would you modify the sentence you cite to have the semantics that to each $x$ in $D$ precisely one value is assigned to it.  Note that this allows a particular value to be assigned to several different $x$s in $D$, but no $x$  is assigned to two (or more) values in $D$.

Comment: @Eric Towers A function f from a set D to a set Y is a rule that assigns one and only one value in Y to each x in D. To say that one value in Y should be unique would imply it could never be assigned to another $x \in D$.

Comment: Do you see that this sentence can *still* be read as distributing values in $Y$ to $x$s in $D$ without duplication?

Comment: I never insinuated that the one value cannot be duplicated, just that the x could be assigned any value in Y, just that it could take than one particular value in Y.

Comment: $f(x)$ **is not a function!** $f$ is a function, $f(x)$ is the function $f$, *evaluated* at the point $x$.

Comment: @Orpheus *To say that one value in Y should be unique would imply it could never be assigned to another x∈D.* No, this does not imply. The uniqueness quantifier is applied to $y$, which is to say, $y$ is unique. Not $x$. You misread the definition.

Comment: It is certainly true that the colloquial sense of "unique" is especially unhelpful in this situation. The mathematical sense in "for every $x$, there exists a unique $y$" does _not_ mean that unequal $x_1$ and $x_2$ cannot have the same value $y$ attached to them, despite perhaps sounding like it. It's the conflict between colloquial and mathematical use of "unique".

Comment: @ paul garrett can you elaborate on what is entailed when you are talking of being unique in a mathematical sense?

Answer (score 0):

A formal and strict definition of $function$ is this:
Let $A, B$ sets; we define a $relation$ from $A$ to $B$ a subset $σ$ of cartesian product $A\times B$. We define a $function$ from $A$ to $B$ a relation $f:=\{(a,b)\subset A\times B| \forall a\in A \exists !b\in B: b=f(a)\}$.

Comment: Formatting tip: Don't use math mode for emphasis – it looks terrible! Instead, *put the text between asterisks for italics*, **between double asterisks for bold**.